# append column values to another column

Tags: r, unix, append

I have a txt file tab delimited as follow:

```
1 aaa apple
1 bbb banana
3 ccc grape
5 ddd orange
```

I would like to create another txt file but this time with the first column values of the original txt file appended in the last column (in this case the third column) with an underscore as follow:

```
1 aaa 1_apple
1 bbb 1_banana
3 ccc 3_grape
5 ddd 5_orange
```

I don't have any programming language preference, but R and Unix would be better if possible...

Thanks

Comment: Look at `tidyr` `unite` or `paste0`. What are the headers of these columns(if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `bash`, you can try:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, $1"_"$3}' file.txt > file2.txt
$ cat file2.txt
1 aaa 1_apple
1 bbb 1_banana
3 ccc 3_grape
5 ddd 5_orange
```

If you want to do in `R`, then try below R code:

```
a <- read_table("file.txt", col_names = FALSE)
a$X3 <- paste(a$X1, a$X3, sep = "_")
write_delim(a, "file2.txt", col_names = FALSE)
```

The file should look like:

```
$ cat file2.txt
1 aaa 1_apple
1 bbb 1_banana
3 ccc 3_grape
5 ddd 5_orange
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$NewColumn<-paste0(df[,1],"_",df[,ncol(df)])
df
V1  V2     V3 NewColumn
1  1 aaa  apple   1_apple
2  1 bbb banana  1_banana
3  3 ccc  grape   3_grape
4  5 ddd orange  5_orange
```

**Writing to .txt**

```
write.table(tidyr::unite(df,New_col,"V1","V3"),"test.txt")
```

With `tidyr`:

```
tidyr::unite(df,New_col,"V1","V3")
```

**Data**:

```
df<-read.table(text="1 aaa apple
1 bbb banana
3 ccc grape
5 ddd orange")
```

Answer (score 1):

With R we can try using `read.csv` and `write.csv`, with a bit of string manipulation:

```
df <- read.csv(file="path/to/your/file.txt")   # one column for entire value
lines <- sapply(df[,1], function(x) {
    parts <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
    parts[3] <- paste0(parts[1], "_", parts[3])
    return(paste0(parts, collapse=" "))
})
write.csv(rbind(lines), file="path/to/your/output.txt")
```